# MySQL Syntax error | You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: java, mysql, sql, select

**Error:**

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'lock WHERE player='SrLolok'' at line 1

**Code:**

```
PreparedStatement search = instance.getConnection().prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM lock WHERE player=?;");
search.setString(1, player);
ResultSet rs = search.executeQuery();
```

Comment: The error message you got has a big clue that the problem is with the word "lock", because it's the first part of what it shows you in the query: `...syntax to use near 'lock WHERE ...`. The part right after "near" is usually a good indicator of something you're doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`lock` is a [reserved word in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html).

If you want to use it, you need to surround it with backticks:

```
SELECT * FROM `lock` WHERE player=?
```

Or better yet, use a table name that does not correspond to a reserved word, so you don't need to worry about this.